# How can I enlarge an image when hovering over part of a vector?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 1 the in the top left of page mostly offscreen, which functions as a home button. I would like to slightly increase it's size when hovered over ,however nothing I try seems to work.

Seeing as the image is a vector which (thank god) is a perfect circle. So with the area tag I could easily make it a home button. Now I would like to enlarge the image when hovering over that area tag, I've tried working with the '+' selector.

How would I do something like this?

This is a code snippet for some context:

```css
.emblem {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -100px 0px 0px -80px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.emblem:hover {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}
.emblem2 {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}
area:hover + .emblem2 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<map name="homemap">
  <area shape="circle" coords="100,100,100" alt="Home button" href="index.html" />
</map>
<img class="emblem" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="UFF emblem" usemap="#homemap" />
<img class="emblem2" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="UFF emblem" usemap="#homemap" />
```

Now this works fine... But only when I hover over the transparent part of the image, and what I want to achieve is the exact opposite.

Comment: Your `<area>` element have 0px x 0px so you can't hover it!

Comment: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/zKyjLx seems to be working fine. adjust the area coordinates to see if it fixes it.

Comment: Im very sorry for taking your time, Seeing as i loved j_lemons idea of expanding the image. Im trying too enlarge the emblem when i hover over the image or area (dont know which works better). This might work if i change the emblem with another emblem like i provided earlier. But after looking j_lemons snippet i definitely would like too use the same emblem.

Comment: @imcvampire how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try just transforming the scale of the image you want to enlarge. something like this:

```css
.emblem {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transform: scale(1); 
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transform: scale(1);   
}
.emblem:hover{
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);   
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<img class="emblem" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="UFF emblem" usemap="#homemap" />
```

Comment: This is not the solution to my problem because it still only expands after hovering over the transparent part of the vector, nonetheless i definitely appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: And it definitely improved the look of the change to the image better :P thanks again

Comment: Sorry for my scattered reactions, i cant seem to edit the previous ones, but is there a way to make it so that the iamge exapnds when hovering over it, and not the transparent part?

Comment: @LukeDerkzen In the code above I was only enlarging the image when that image was hovered over. Might have to get some clarity from you. So are you saying you have two elements, one is a vector and the second is an image, and the desired interaction is that when you hover over the vector (asset one) the image (asset two) gets bigger?

Comment: The image im trying to enlarge is a vector, and it's the only image i'm using, ofcourse the image has a transparent part all around the vector, and currently when i hover over that transparent part, the vector enlarges, but the vector has to enlarge when i actually hover over the vector itself. Not the transparent sapce around it. So just 1 image, I hope this clarifies it for you.

Comment: If its only a circle I would suggest using an svg. I think to achieve what you are describing with an image map would require some javascript. But to get the desired interaction only when the hover is on the image you have to target the hover to the element containing the image. If you target the parent element with the hover then you will get the hover interaction when the user hovers over the parent and child. Here is a fiddle with a couple of different examples: https://jsfiddle.net/5cktu2rv/1/

Comment: I don't really mind how this effect is achieved, as long as it works. I just started with js so that might be hard, but I checked out the CSS-tricks page for SVG and it seems to be exactly what I need. So I hope I can make it using that. And about your fiddle examples, I could all make them work like that, that wouldn't make any trouble the problem is that I only want the circle to be clickable and not the entire image (also the transparent parts). Thanks for your time!, I'll check out if i can do it using SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS:

```css
.img-box {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
}
.img-link {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.img-link a,
.img-link a:active,
.img-link a:focus,
.img-link a:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.fa-hover {
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: x-large;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.fa-hover:hover + .emblem {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.emblem {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="img-box">
  <a class="img-link" href="https://www.google.ca" target="_window">
    <div class="fa-hover">
      <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    </div>
    <img class="emblem" src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/A0x3jzuH1qRkE10HcTiT4qQr_6iAqVg-CTsoIqxnoIFyv92V91WI3KqiVlOvLtfoMRg=w300" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Downside to the '+' selector is the element your hovering on has to be above the 'img' tag, but with css that icon can be moved.

Comment: I understand what you're getting at. But after seeing j_lemons idea i prefer to be using one image, and the problem i currently have doing that is that the image only enlarges when I hover across the transparent part of the image. This is most likely because of the area tag, because it has a size of 0x0 according to the developer tool.  Is there any way to increase this size, but into something circular??? Thanks in advance.